# GoogleSheets API download non-public spreadsheet as csv

Tags: curl, google-api, google-sheets, wget, google-data-api

This is a very broad question, I'm only looking for general advice/directions to a tutorial. I would like to download an unpublished googlesheet as a .csv file locally. I've seen other questions about downloading public published google sheets, but I couldn't find any solutions to download unpublished sheets. Is there a simple way to use wget/curl command in a shell to download an unpublished google sheet as a .csv?

If not, I've looked into Google API, and found [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/index) on Google sheets API. I'm not experienced in Java or APIs at all, but I was able to set up a Client Library in Java in Microsoft Visual Studio and generate an oAuth2.0 ClientID. Does anyone know of a tutorial on how to set up/use GoogleSheets API for this purpose?

Comment: Have you been granted access to this non-public document?

Comment: yes I own the document and share it with my coworkers. However, it contains info I'd rather not make public so I'd like to require a user ID to view if I were to publish it

Answer (score -1):

From what I know - you cannot download a googlesheet locally in your machine. You can, however, "download" the googlesheet to a designated folder in your Google Drive, which you can have synced to a local drive in your machine...

Comment: To download Google doc types, you export them to a "real" filetype - like CSV, txt, xlsx, docx